# How can i insert data to a schema array in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, save, schema, assign

I have a schema as shown below and I was trying to insert a value to that schema but data is not being assigned. How we can assign data to a schema array in nodejs?
building is my schema instance.

my schema is shown below

```
geoValues: [
        {
            latitude: Number,

            longitude: Number,

    }
    ],
```

I tried like below for assigning data to my schema

```
building. geoValues.latitude = latitude;
 building. geoValues.longitude = longitude;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether your mongoose schema looks like this,

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const buildingSchema = new Schema({
  geoValues: [{
    latitude: Number,
    longitude: Number
  }]
});
```

Comment: yeah looks similar, rather than creating direct I made an instance of building and worked, but my problem is in assigning some data to this from my controller

Comment: Did you create a model for building? You need to pass this schema to the corresponding model before saving the document to mongodb.

Comment: yes I created the model as yu made and then tried to assign data to the model instance  in controller but since an array I don't know how to assign a value to an array to an instance of schema ?

Comment: Okay. You can try like this, building.geoValues[0].latitude = latitude